# bluetooth enabling dialog - HOME button disabling

Tags: android

all my activities use code below to disable home button:

```
@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow()
{  
       this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);     
       super.onAttachedToWindow();  
}
```

but main activity turn bluetooth ON by

```
        Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
        startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
```

that open bluetooth enabling dialog

How can I prevent exit my app in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was solved by

> BluetoothAdapter.enable()

and listening for the ACTION_STATE_CHANGED broadcast Intent.